# example of a aws listener rule using cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I'm trying to use python and aws CDK to build a application listener rule for the load balancer. I have it working through the console but would really like to get it to work in my python script.  The load balancer and the listeners are both being created but the listener rule is stops the script.
This is how I've tried to get it started

```
buildrule = elb.ApplicationListenerRule(
          scope = self,
          id = "HTTP:80",
          listener = httpslistenerBUILD,
          priority = 1,
          action = "redirectResponse",
          pathPattern = ["/Index"] )
```

Here is what it looks like using the console [image: aws console listener rule]

Comment: What do you mean "stops the script"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It throws an error that the PathPatterns is not valid when I run cdk synth